# Configuring application busy Window

Tags: crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

We have configured WER to generate dump files on a server path and the dump takes a while.

During this time if the user clicks the application the following window is shown on some machines (the window says more or less: "The application is busy. If you wait maybe the application works again. End process / Cancel):

[image]

On some other machines when the user clicks on the dying application the process is terminated without asking anything and aborting the generation of the dump.

Does someone how can we configure this window to appear or not?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is your application running only locally within your company?  WER is typically used to trap a crash and upload it to the Microsoft crash reporting systems.  I'm not sure how your framework is set up.

Comment: Wer offers functionality to manage the reports locally. It's called localdumps

Comment: So, your application is for in-house use only?

Comment: @rrirower: yes it is. We have our own mechanism to process the local dumps without going thru Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Unresponsive applications are detected by the Windows Manager. It looks at the Windows Message Queue and checks whether or not it becomes empty.

There is a 5 seconds [HungAppTimeout (MS Technet)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130107004912/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978614.aspx) in `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop`. However, this setting is global, so it's not a good idea to apply it. This setting is not to be confused with the 20 seconds [WaitToKillAppTimeout](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301215417/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx) which can be shown at system logoff.

A per-application solution is [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which your application calls to prevent the dimmed window happening. This needs modifications in your code.

If you can't or don't want to change it in the code since that will affect all users and not only the ones in your company, you can apply the same setting with the [Application Compatibility Toolkit (MS Technet)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130919034820/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa905066). The fix is called "NoGhost" there.

Comment: The main question is: why on some machine the dialog appears and on others it doesn't doing the same action?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia: agreed, that's also an interesting question, but you didn't ask it until now :-) Since that is not programming related and more an administration task, this better suits SuperUser.